# Why Caffe's Accuracy layer's bottoms consist of InnerProduct and Label?

Tags: caffe, mnist

I'm new to **caffe**, in the *MNIST* example, I was thought that label should compared with softmax layers, but it was not the situation in `lenet.prototxt`.
I wonder why use `InnerProduct` result and label to get the accuracy, it seems unreasonable. Was it because I missed something in the layers?

Answer (score 1):

The output dimension of the last inner product layer is 10, which corresponds to the number of classes (digits 0~9) of your problem.
The loss layer, takes two blobs, the first one being the prediction(ip2) and the second one being the label provided by the data layer.

```
loss_layer = SoftmaxLossLayer(name="loss", bottoms=[:ip2,:label])
```

It does not produce any outputs - all it does is to compute the loss function value, report it when backpropagation starts, and initiates the gradient with respect to ip2. This is where all magic starts.
After training ( in TEST phase), In the last layer desire results come from multiply weights and ip1( that are computed in last layer ); And each of class( one of 10 neurons) has max value is choosen.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explaination, I just found that I have misunderstanding with crossentropy loss function, in fact, there is no need to know the softmax probability when calculating the loss, just using the activation of the last layer and the ground-truth are enough. Am I right?^.^ Thank you so much.

Comment: I have thought over about it, I'm sure again there must be something implicit in Accuracy Layer, because we always compare the    ' max(ip2)<=> label',  not 'ip2<=>label'. So, is the max() operation hide in Accuracy Layer?Otherwise, a max activation of 0.99 in ip2 won't equals to the label value 1.